# Type Mismatch 13 Error - Referencing an object

Tags: excel, vba

I created a subroutine to store all the cells in a worksheet in an object called "CNrng3".

```
Sub GetCLRange()
Dim CLrng1 As Range
Dim CLrng2 As Range
Sheets("Cancel").Activate
Set CLrng1 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
Set CLrng2 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
If Not CLrng1 Is Nothing Then
    Set CLrng3 = Range([a1], Cells(CLrng1.Row, CLrng2.Column))
Application.Goto CLrng3
Else
    MsgBox "sheet is blank", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Now, I want to reference this object to create a pivot with the data:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    CLrng3.Cells, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="CancelSummary!R1C1", TableName:="CancelPivot", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

The issue is that I'm getting "Type Mismatch Error 13" when I run this part of the code. Does anyone have an idea why I may be receiving this error and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: How have you declared CLrng3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try recording the code with the macro recorder you will see that the SourceRange expects to see an address such as `"Cancel!R1C1:R10C5"` which includes the sheet name

So rather than

`SourceData:= CLrng3.Cells`

try

`SourceData:=(Clrng3.Parent.Name & "!" & Clrng3.Address)`

which returns in three parts

1. "Cancel" (as the name of the parent of your range)
2. "!"
3. and something like A1:E10

giving `Cancel!A1:E10`

```
 Sub GetCLRange()
    Dim CLrng1 As Range
    Dim CLrng2 As Range
    Dim Clrng3 As Range
    Sheets("Cancel").Activate
    Set CLrng1 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Set CLrng2 = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    If Not CLrng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set Clrng3 = Range([a1], Cells(CLrng1.Row, CLrng2.Column))
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                                          ("'" & Clrng3.Parent.Name & "'!" & Clrng3.Address), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
                                          TableDestination:="CancelSummary!R1C1", TableName:="CancelPivot", _
                                          DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
        Application.Goto Clrng3
    Else
        MsgBox "sheet is blank", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, but have you tested that this makes a difference? Some properties do accept arguments of type `Range` even though the macro recorder always supplies them as a `String` containing the range's address. A case in point is the `.Values` and `.XValues` properties of the `Series` object.

Comment: In this case the pivottable is being created in a second sheet ""CancelSummary", so the parent sheet name of the required range "Cancel" is a fundamental requirement. Which may be slightly different to the point you are making

Comment: +1 You may want to wrap the worksheet name in single-quotes, just in case the worksheet name has spaces. If it doesn't, Excel faithfully drops the single quotes with no consequence.

Comment: JP - good point, I should have picked up on this originally to make the solution more robust. I will update the solution accordingly